Cannot overide javafx.platform.properties in JavaFXPorts grade compilation
I have been playing around with various config options to try and get a compiled APK to work on a target device.  I have been trying to increase the stack size and have noticed that in the samples folder of the dalvik SDK there is a property android.monocle.stackSize in the javafx.plaform.properties file. However I have been having trouble changing this.
I have tried placing a replacement properties file in the resources folder but when I build it complains that there are two versions of the file, I assume because normally the file is auto-generated.  I have been trying to configure the packagingOptions (as documented in https://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_android_4) in the build.gradle file to control the inclusion/exclusion criteria.  I have been trying use functions like pickFirst('/someFile') and exclude('/someFile') but these do not seem to have any impact on the final APK.  Am I doing something wrong?
